# /tmp flooded with ".myapp" files

Tags: centos5, tmp, files, symfony

On my new server (dedicated, CentOs5), 2 or 3 .myapp files (like "51b9dc4cc246f.myapp", ~500 Mo) is created every minute under /tmp, fulling my harddisk at an alarming speed.

There is nothing in `crontab -e`.

Any ideas from where this can come from ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I've no idea what would create the files but you you try running [fuser](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) on one that is being generated to find out which process is creating them and work back from the PID.

```
fuser -v /tmp/51b9dc4cc246f.myapp
```

will hopefully give you some information you can use e.g.

```
fuser -v  /var/run/crond.pid
                     USER       PID  ACCESS COMMAND
/var/run/crond.pid:  root       1698 F....  crond
```

which shows us that the user root is running crond with PID 1698 which has the /var/run/crond.pid file open for writing(F).

Comment: No response from the first command, and the second one either :
`USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/run/crond.pid:  root       2601 F.... crond`

Comment: @NicolasReynolds: they are only example cpommands - you should use fuser on a .myapp file that is being actively written to.

Comment: After searching, it appears that it was the XHPROF extension that created the files, /tmp being the default folder.

Debuuging XHPROF solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check which process has a .myapp file open, as root:

```
lsof | grep -i myapp
```

This may give you a clue.

If not, then investigate a little more, check what type of file is it:

```
file 51b9dc4cc246f.myapp
```

If it's text just open it with less. If not use strings to see if it has anything readable in it:

```
strings 51b9dc4cc246f.myapp | less
```

If that doesn't get any clue, i'll bet to leave a loop running, preferably in a screen session with the lsof command, every minute or less

```
while [ true ]; do lsof | grep -i myapp; sleep 30; done
```

Good luck!

Comment: No response for this command

Comment: It seems to be generated by Symfony2. It's maybe related to the cache creation, with which I'm experiencing troubles at the moment.

Comment: There it is then ;)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here recommend fuser or lsof, and those are technically better solution. However those tools can be tedious, so here is an alternative which might be quicker.

Creating that many files will consume a significant amount of processing time.

Run top. Sort by CPU usage. Watch for a few minutes. The process which is writing that many files will likely be in the top 3-4 consumers of CPU. To verify, try stopping each process one at a time. Does the bad behavior go away?